# Install RAPIDS on WSL2 Ubuntu 20.04 distribution in Windows 11

Tags: cuda, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2, rapids

I followed the updated instructions, [available here](https://docs.rapids.ai/notices/rgn0024/), to install RAPIDS on WSL2 Windows 11. As indicated in the instructions, I have not installed CUDA on the Ubuntu distribution. I copied the following command from the official website:

```
    rapids=22.06 python=3.9 cudatoolkit=11.5 \
    jupyterlab dash graphistry pycaret tensorflow
```

I thought that even if my current CUDA version is 11.7, the rapids version requiring CUDA 11.5 would be forward compatible. Given that conda found a large list of conflicts I guess this is not the case.

After reading the instructions again I noticed it said that CUDA would be installed along with rapids. So I thought that removing the nvidia channel and the `cudatoolkit` parameter would somehow fix the issue but I got this output:

```
Package python conflicts for:
rapids=22.06 -> cuda-python[version='>=11.5,<12'] -> python[version='3.8.*|3.9.*|>=3.10,<3.11.0a0|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0|>=3.6|>=3.7|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0']
rapids=22.06 -> python[version='>=3.8,<3.9.0a0|>=3.9,<3.10.0a0']
python=3.9The following specifications were found to be incompatible with your system:

  - feature:/linux-64::__glibc==2.31=0
  - python=3.9 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - rapids=22.06 -> cucim=22.06 -> __glibc[version='>=2.17|>=2.17,<3.0.a0']

Your installed version is: 2.31
```

Do I need to downgrade CUDA Toolkit in Windows 11 or upgrade the libraries indicated in the output?

I would also like to know if it would be a feasible alternative to install CUDA on a Ubuntu distribution from Virtualbox. In which case I would then create the VM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue is that you're trying to install `tensorflow` on `cudatoolkit=11.5`.  You may need to install it from the picker with `cudatoolkit=11.2` or just change it in your install command.